# How can I sort a model that contains user as a foreign key to a page that shows every user's data?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to make my homepage main that shows every user's information.

```
on Models.py (simplified, not actual code):
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    level = models.IntegerField()

class History(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    history = models.CharField()

on HTML:
{% for user in users %}
    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
    {% for history in histories.objects.filter(name__exact=User.id) %}
        <p> {{ history }} </p>//sorted history that contains 'user' as ForeignKey
    {% endfor %}
    <p>{{ user.level }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Showing an information in User model was successful, using above method, but I couldn't sort History model for 'user'. How can I show this model, getting key from 'user' and sort it?

I'm now using the latest version of Django, 2.1, and I already tried to get pk value from 'user', and send it to the views.py, but it was not helpful.

```
Expected: 
<p>User 01</p> //Name
<p>Changed name user01 to User 01</p>
<p>Level increased to 25</p>
<p>Level increased to 26</p>  //History
<p>LV 26</p> //Level

<p>User 02</p> //Name
<p>Level increased to 32</p>
<p>Changed name user02 to User 02</p>
<p>Level increased to 33</p>  //History
<p>LV 33</p> //Level

Actual:
<p>User 01</p>
<p></p>
<p>Lv 26</p>

<p>User 02</p>
<p></p>
<p>Lv 33</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it.
One way is to extend the Manager instance and add custom method which returns records sorted by id. Like so:

```
class HistoryManager(models.Manager):
    def latest_records(self):
        return super().get_queryset().order_by('-id')

class History(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='histories')
    history = models.CharField()
    objects = HistoryManager()

{% for user in users %}
    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
    {% for history in user.histories.latest_records %}
        <p> {{ history }} </p>//sorted history that contains 'user' as ForeignKey
    {% endfor %}
    <p>{{ user.level }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Another way of doing it is to create a method in the User model's instance

```
class History(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='histories')
    history = models.CharField()

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    level = models.IntegerField()
    def latest_history():
        return self.histories.order_by('-id')

{% for user in users %}
    <p>{{ user.name }}</p>
    {% for history in user.latest_history %}
        <p> {{ history }} </p>//sorted history that contains 'user' as ForeignKey
    {% endfor %}
    <p>{{ user.level }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `latest()` returns one record (the latest one), not a sorted queryset.

Comment: Yep you are right. I've changed it to .order_by('-id') .

Comment: Everything's are working like a charm! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you always need the same sort order, you can add a default sort to the `History` class:

```
class History(models.Model):
    # define fields...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
```

The upside is that every `History` queryset will be sorted as specified without any further action on your part. The downside is that the queryset will *always* be sorted, potentially impacting performance. So if you don't always need it, it's better to either define a method as proposed by Kristiyan or simply constructing an appropriately ordered queryset in the view and passing it to the template (creating filtered querysets directly in the template as shown in your code won't work as far as I know):

```
for user in users:
    user.sorted_history = History.objects.filter(name = user).order_by('-id')
    # or .order_by('-timestamp'), .order_by('history') etc. as needed
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give models a default sort.